# How to get an array with the counts of each field with the same parameter in Django in get_context_data?

Tags: python, django

I use a ListView for a template that displays all the Vehicles in the database. Each Vehicle can have more Wheels and I'm trying to display in the same tempalte how many views each sensor has.

The models are related to eachother by a field called "vehicle_id". Any idea how I could do this in views.py?

The line that works to an extent is the following

```
context['number_of_wheels'] = wheels.objects.filter(vehicle_id= F('vehicle_id')).count()
```

However, this counts all Wheels in the database and displays the same value for all entries. Any idea how I could count, store and display them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add these numbers to a context variable. It would probably add more complexity, for example to match that number with the sensors.

You can `.annotate(..)` your `Sensor`s, so in the `queryset`, you can write:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from app.models import Sensor

class SensorListView(ListView):
    queryset = Sensor.objects.annotate(
        nviews=Count('sensorview')
    )
    template = 'some_template.html'
```

Each `Sensor` that originates from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `nview`s that contains the number of related `SensorView`s.

You can then render this in `some_template.html`, like:

```
{% for sensor in object_list %}
    {{ sensor }}: {{ sensor.nviews }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Andrei: but your model is `Sensor` right? Then you should count the relation in reverse, so `Count('sensorview')`.

Comment: @Andrei: furthermore you can not use `queryset....`, since the queryset is not defined before it is used. The above should simply add an extra attribute to the `Sensor`s you query anyway.

Comment: yes, the model is `Sensor`. I put the queryset line in views, under the class `SensorListview`

Comment: @Andrei: but why would you do that? You only make it harder to retrieve the number of views, even if that would work. You can simply change the queryset of your `ListView`, and in the template render it like `{% for sensor in object_list %} {{ sensor.nviews }} {% endfor %}`. In terms of modeling it makes no sense to aggregate over the non-root model.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do, I actually have that for loop in my template. The issue is that it iterates through the sensor objects, not the sensorView objects. I would like for each Sensor object that the for loop iterates through, to get a count of how many SensorView objects that Sensor object has attributed.

Comment: @Andrei: that is *exactly* what this answer does. The count of `SensorView`s is attributed to *each `Sensor`* in the `ListView` in the `.nviews`.

Comment: @Andrei: so there is *no* need at all to add extra `get_context_data` here.